# mysql - using the same column in where clause

Tags: mysql

Below is my table, how can i get the `item_id` with selecting multiple `item_subcategory_id`.
For example i need to get the `item_id` with an `item_subcategory_id` of 86,51 and 1. I should only get the `item_id` 1 even though `item_id` 2 has an `item_subcategory_id` of 51

Please note that the number of item_subcategory_id is dynamic.

[image]

I tried the query

```
SELECT item_id 
FROM item_specs 
WHERE item_subcategory_id = 86 AND 
      item_subcategory_id=51 AND 
      item_subcategory_id = 1
```

but it displays an empty result

Comment: I suggest that you attempt a query, then show us what you tried and what went wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the count and compare the result of count to the no of  distinct `item_subcategory_id`s you provide in `in()` clause like in your case distinct `item_subcategory_id`s is 3 ,so this will result only those `item_id`s which has all of these provided `item_subcategory_id`s

```
select * from table
where item_subcategory_id in(1,51,86)
group by item_id
having count(distinct item_subcategory_id) =3
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `AND` operator to combine your conditions

```
select item_category_id
from mytable
where item_id = 1 and item_subcategory_id in (86, 51, 1);
```